# Почему цифра 9 не выводится?

Tags: javascript

```js
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 

  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; 
  }

  alert( i ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что при `i = 9` и `j = 3` выражение `i % j == 0` является правдой (`true`)

Comment: А почему j = 3 если j = 2? Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @Arthur так это начальное значение `j`, а в следующей итерации он увеличивается на единицу и становится равным 3

Comment: Можете объяснить алгоритм? Не могу понять когда переменная j увеличивается и когда уменьшается? Спасибо

Comment: @Arthur Вам надо основательно прочитать про [циклы в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for). В данном случае после проверки `if` если условие было `false`, то `continue` не срабатывает, выполняется `j++`  и начинается новая итерация внутренного `for`, где уже `j = 3`